# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow to create a link to a document

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I was initially tasked with branding sharepoint, which is fine, but I've been asked to do a few other things.

The main thing I've been asked to do is to upload a file with a link to it in other locations.

For example, I have several folders in my document library, let's say folders 1 ... 5 - each with specific permissions so that only certain groups can view them. Now, what I need to be able to do is to upload a file in one location, but link it to other locations (this would probably done using a lookup).

So, I upload a file to folder 1, but when uploading it I select that I want to provide a link to it in folders 4 and 5. How would I go about this? Would the permissions apply to the link?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use workflow and a 'link' content type in the document library to do this, however, permissions would be an issue. Users with access to Folder 1 can see a link to a document in Folder 2, but if they do not have access to Folder 2 they cannot view the document itself.

You could use Workflow to clone the document to multiple locations, thus avoiding the permissions roadblock, however you would then also need workflow to keep the documents in sync with updates etc...

Comment: I've never created a workflow, so I'm not entirely sure where to start. I've thought of another solution though, and that is to edit permissions on upload. i.e. 

A file is uploaded to folder 1, but with a meta tag like "also visible to" set to folder 2. This way, people who have access to folder 2 will see folder 1, but only this document.  

How does that sound? Ideally, i'd still prefer to do it the initial way though. :\